# Error creating an instance in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have created an IAM user and when that user tries to spin up an EC2 instance he sees the following VPC error,what do I need to do to grant him sufficient privileges.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IAM console dashboard,

1. go to Policies, click "create policy",
2. Next, click "Create your own policy"
3. give it a name (e.g. my-ec2) and   description (always use your own prefix, for easy filter search)
4. Under the "Policy Document" , put following entries into the box.
   Then click validate to confirm it is valid, click "Create Policy"
   afterwards.

   ```
   {"Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
       {
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
       }]}
   ```

Now back to the policies dashboard, just enter your policies prefix (e.g. my-ec2) as filter,  open it, under "attach entities", attach the user name.

Comment: Thank you @mootmoot ,does this policy allow elastic IPs as well?

Comment: It is a "*" ,  means everything. Unless you want create a special EIP allocation policy for particular group of peope. E.g.  
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html#ex-eip

Answer (score 2):

The error means that your IAM user doesn't have enough permissions to create a VPC.
Did you attach a policy to your IAM user (it's a JSON document that describes what actions are allowed for a user)?
[This guide describes how to manage your policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)

In your particular case, you need full access over EC2.
The policy is below:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1458205035000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]}
```